# Convert data from long format to wide format with multiple measure columns

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I am having trouble figuring out the most elegant and flexible way to switch data from long format to wide format when I have more than one measure variable I want to bring along.

For example, here's a simple data frame in long format.  `ID` is the subject, `TIME` is a time variable, and `X` and `Y` are measurements made of `ID` at `TIME`:

```
> my.df <- data.frame(ID=rep(c("A","B","C"), 5), TIME=rep(1:5, each=3), X=1:15, Y=16:30)
> my.df

   ID TIME  X  Y
1   A    1  1 16
2   B    1  2 17
3   C    1  3 18
4   A    2  4 19
5   B    2  5 20
6   C    2  6 21
7   A    3  7 22
8   B    3  8 23
9   C    3  9 24
10  A    4 10 25
11  B    4 11 26
12  C    4 12 27
13  A    5 13 28
14  B    5 14 29
15  C    5 15 30
```

If I just wanted to turn the values of `TIME` into column headers containing the include `X`, I know I can use `cast()` from the `reshape` package (or `dcast()` from `reshape2`):

```
> cast(my.df, ID ~ TIME, value="X")
  ID 1 2 3  4  5
1  A 1 4 7 10 13
2  B 2 5 8 11 14
3  C 3 6 9 12 15
```

But what I really want to do is also bring along `Y` as another measure variable, and have the column names reflect both the measure variable name and the time value:

```
  ID X_1 X_2 X_3  X_4 X_5 Y_1 Y_2 Y_3 Y_4 Y_5
1  A   1   4   7   10  13  16  19  22  25  28
2  B   2   5   8   11  14  17  20  23  26  29
3  C   3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
```

(FWIW, I don't really care if all the `X`'s are first followed by the `Y`'s, or if they are interleaved as `X_1`, `Y_1`, `X_2`, `Y_2`, etc.)

I can get close to this by *cast*-ing the long data twice and merging the results, though the column names need some work, and I would need to tweak it if I needed to add a 3rd or 4th variable in addition to `X` and `Y`:

```
merge(
cast(my.df, ID ~ TIME, value="X"),
cast(my.df, ID ~ TIME, value="Y"),
by="ID", suffixes=c("_X","_Y")
)
```

Seems like some combination of functions in `reshape2` and/or `plyr` should be able to do this more elegantly that my attempt, as well as handling multiple measure variables more cleanly. Something like `cast(my.df, ID ~ TIME, value=c("X","Y"))`, which isn't valid.  But I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In order to handle multiple variables like  you want, you need to `melt` the data you have before casting it.

```
library("reshape2")

dcast(melt(my.df, id.vars=c("ID", "TIME")), ID~variable+TIME)
```

which gives

```
  ID X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 Y_1 Y_2 Y_3 Y_4 Y_5
1  A   1   4   7  10  13  16  19  22  25  28
2  B   2   5   8  11  14  17  20  23  26  29
3  C   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
```

---

EDIT based on comment:

The data frame

```
num.id = 10 
num.time=10 
my.df <- data.frame(ID=rep(LETTERS[1:num.id], num.time), 
                    TIME=rep(1:num.time, each=num.id), 
                    X=1:(num.id*num.time), 
                    Y=(num.id*num.time)+1:(2*length(1:(num.id*num.time))))
```

gives a different result (all entries are 2) because the `ID`/`TIME` combination does not indicate a unique row. In fact, there are two rows with each `ID`/`TIME` combinations. `reshape2` assumes a single value for each possible combination of the variables and will apply a summary function to create a single variable is there are multiple entries. That is why there is the warning

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
```

You can get something that works if you add another variable which breaks that redundancy.

```
my.df$cycle <- rep(1:2, each=num.id*num.time)
dcast(melt(my.df, id.vars=c("cycle", "ID", "TIME")), cycle+ID~variable+TIME)
```

This works because `cycle`/`ID`/`time` now uniquely defines a row in `my.df`.

Comment: I was trying to assess which solution is fastest, but found a problem with your code if the data frame is as follow: num.id = 10
num.time=10


my.df <- data.frame(ID=rep(LETTERS[1:num.id], num.time), 
TIME=rep(1:num.time, each=num.id), X=1:(num.id*num.time),
 Y=(num.id*num.time)+1:(2*length(1:(num.id*num.time))))

Comment: Perfect, thanks Brian.  Since cast seemed to be working, I didn't realize melt was still necessary.

Answer (score 24):

This answer is pretty old, maybe find some newer info.

```
   reshape(my.df,
           idvar = "ID",
           timevar = "TIME",
           direction = "wide")
```

gives

```
  ID X.1 Y.1 X.2 Y.2 X.3 Y.3 X.4 Y.4 X.5 Y.5
1  A   1  16   4  19   7  22  10  25  13  28
2  B   2  17   5  20   8  23  11  26  14  29
3  C   3  18   6  21   9  24  12  27  15  30
```

Answer (score 17):

Using the `data.table_1.9.5`, this can be done without the `melt` as it can handle multiple `value.var` columns.  You can install it from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(my.df), ID~TIME, value.var=c('X', 'Y'))
 #   ID 1_X 2_X 3_X 4_X 5_X 1_Y 2_Y 3_Y 4_Y 5_Y
 #1:  A   1   4   7  10  13  16  19  22  25  28
 #2:  B   2   5   8  11  14  17  20  23  26  29
 #3:  C   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
```

Comment: Thank you for the above solution. When I run this code, I get the following warning message: any advice on it, please?

```Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'```

@akrun This relates to one of my questions in the post:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830282/complex-data-reshaping-into-wide-format-where-input-is-a-mix-of-long-and-wide-da>

Comment: @Sandy taht is because you have duplicate elements, so `dcast` default to use `length`.  Perhaps you want `dcast(setDT(my.df), ID + rowid(ID) ~ TIME, value.var = c("X", "Y"))`

Answer (score 8):

The [`pivot_wider()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) function is [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html)'s 2nd generation approach (released in tidyr 1.0.0).

```r
library(magrittr); requireNamespace("tidyr");

my.df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from  = c(TIME), # Can accommodate more variables, if needed.
    values_from = c(X, Y)
  )
```

**Result**:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 11
  ID      X_1   X_2   X_3   X_4   X_5   Y_1   Y_2   Y_3   Y_4   Y_5
  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         1     4     7    10    13    16    19    22    25    28
2 B         2     5     8    11    14    17    20    23    26    29
3 C         3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30
```

This is probably preferable to the [previous tidyr approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126250/1082435)
(that uses a combination of [`gather()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) and [`spread()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html)).

More capabilities are described in the [pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).
This example is particularly concise because your desired specifications match the defaults of the `id_cols` and `names_sep`.

Comment: Surprised this one isn't upvoted more. If you are dealing with a really large data frame and/or a lot of columns this is the only one that will work. All of the other solutions run out of memory. Not quite sure what the threshold is but I was processing a data frame with 6M records and 24 columns.

Answer (score 7):

*Note -Sept 2019*: within [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html), the `gather()`+`spread()` approach (described in this answer) has more or less been replaced by the `pivot_wider()` approach (described in `[this newer tidyr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57965244/1082435)).  For current info about the transition, see the [pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).

---

Here's a solution with the [tidyr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidyr) package, which has essentially replaced [reshape](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reshape) and [reshape2](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=reshape2).    As with those two packages, the strategy it to make the dataset longer first, and then wider.

```
library(magrittr); requireNamespace("tidyr"); requireNamespace("dplyr")
my.df %>%
  tidyr::gather(key=variable, value=value, c(X, Y)) %>%   # Make it even longer.
  dplyr::mutate(                                          # Create the spread key.
    time_by_variable   = paste0(variable, "_", TIME)
  ) %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, time_by_variable, value) %>%          # Retain these three.
  tidyr::spread(key=time_by_variable, value=value)        # Spread/widen.
```

After the [`tidyr::gather()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) call, the intermediate dataset is:

```
ID TIME variable value
1   A    1        X     1
2   B    1        X     2
3   C    1        X     3
...
28  A    5        Y    28
29  B    5        Y    29
30  C    5        Y    30
```

The eventual result is:

```
  ID X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 X_5 Y_1 Y_2 Y_3 Y_4 Y_5
1  A   1   4   7  10  13  16  19  22  25  28
2  B   2   5   8  11  14  17  20  23  26  29
3  C   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30
```

[`tidyr::unite()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html) is an alternative, suggested by @JWilliman.  This is functionally equivalent to the [`dplyr::mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) and [`dplyr::select()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html) combination above, when the `remove` parameter is true (which is the default).

If you're not accustomed to this type of manipulation, the `tidyr::unite()` may be a small obstacle because it's one more function you have to learn & remember.  However, it's benefits include (a) more concise code (*ie*, four lines are replaced by one) and (b) fewer places to repeat variable names (*ie*, you don't have to repeat/modify variables in the `dplyr::select()` clause).

```
my.df %>%
  tidyr::gather(key=variable, value=value, c(X, Y)) %>%           # Make it even longer.
  tidyr::unite("time_by_variable", variable, TIME, remove=T) %>%  # Create the spread key `time_by_variable` while simultaneously dropping `variable` and `TIME`.
  tidyr::spread(key=time_by_variable, value=value)                # Spread/widen.
```

Comment: The line `dplyr::mutate(time_by_variable   = paste0(variable, "_", TIME))` can be replaced with `tidyr::unite("time_by_variable", variable, TIME)`.

Comment: I agree, @JWilliman.  I thought the explicit `mutate()` and `paste0()` calls made the intention clearer, and avoided introducing a new function.  But I am seeing `tidyr::unite()` used more in the past year.  I'll append the response to reflect your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but the following solution may also work.

```
# Input
my.df <- data.frame(ID=rep(c("A","B","C"), 5), TIME=rep(1:5, each=3), X=1:15, Y=16:30)

# Conversion into wide format
my.df %>%
  pivot_wider(ID, c(TIME), 
              values_from = c(X, Y),
              names_glue = '{.value}_{TIME}')
```

1- With this solution, you can adjust the column names by setting them in the `names_glue` option either as

```
names_glue = '{.value}_{TIME}' or
names_glue = '{TIME}_{.value}'
```

2- Similarly, with this solution, you can join two or more fields e.g., `c(TIME, DAY, MONTH)` and then correspondingly update the `names_glue` option:

```
names_glue = '{TIME}_{DAY}_{MONTH}_{.value}'
```