# Dataframe reshape/transpose using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, transpose

I have a data frame in the below format 
[Original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSUFV.png)

For a given ID; the age ,sex and status remain the same.

I want to do a couple of transformations

1. Have a single row for each "Id" and "Type".
2. Find unique values in "Tablet" column and do a transpose .
3. Transpose "Level" column and have the values corresponding to each tablet under newly transposed tablet column.Empty cells have to be filled with "NA".

The desired output format is attached below for reference.[desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT1Mi.png)

I have tried using dcast and reshape; tidyr with dplyr using gather and spread,however am not able to acheive the 3rd transformation

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate of your assignment, but it should be close enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589693.  If not, consider reposting with mvce elements. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `spread()` function in the `tidyr` package:

Set up packages and data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


 df=data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
  age=c(3,3,3,3,3,51,51),
  sex=c('f','f','f','f','f','m','m'),
  type=c('a','a','a','b','b','a','a'),
  tablet=c('t1','t2','t3','t1','t5','t3','t10'),
  level=c(1,2,3,1,4,2,3),
  status=c('n','n','n','n','n','y','y')
  )
```

Use `group_by()` to get you result by id and type.

Use `spread()` to transpose the data with `tablet` column containing the keys for the column names, and `level` column containing the values. `spread()` will fill in blanks with `NA` by default.

Use `select()` to rearrange columns into the desired format:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id,type) %>% 
  spread(tablet, level) %>% 
  select(id,age,sex,type,t1,t2,t3,t5,t10,status)
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The code works nearly perfect. I want to have all levels for a sample ID in one row. Now I get for 4 rows for ID "1" and 2 rows for ID "2". tried a coalesce and merge.. not much luck.. finally got it working by doing a slice "fill(everything(), .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = "up") %>%
  slice(1)" .. The performance is not great though. Suggestions for any alternatives ?