# Going to wide format by the values in one column in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

My data looks like this

```
mydf = data.frame(length=c(1,1,2,2,3), 
                  type=c("A","B","A","B","A"), 
                  val1=1:5, 
                  val2=6:10)


> mydf
length type val1 val2
     1    A    1    6
     1    B    2    7
     2    A    3    8
     2    B    4    9
     3    A    5   10
```

In this example there is no `type` "B" for `length` 3. That is typical: every `length` has at least one `type` but not always both. There are only the two `types`.

My objective is to put this data into a "wider" form by `type` so it looks like this, with zeros (or NAs) for the missing values:

```
  length  val1.A  val1.B  val2.A   val2.B
       1       1       2       6        7
       2       3       4       8        9
       3       5       0      10        0
```

I've been trying to do this with `spread()` but cannot get it to work--I thought I would be able to specify `type` and `length` as the key and the other columns as the values but that doesn't seem possible. Is there a tidyverse way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible dupe [Convert data from long format to wide format with multiple measure columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589693/convert-data-from-long-format-to-wide-format-with-multiple-measure-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a `gather` on 'val1', 'val2' to convert the data into 'long' format, `unite` the 'key', 'type' columns to a single column and then `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(mydf, key, val, val1:val2) %>% 
   unite(key, key, type, sep=".") %>% 
   spread(key, val, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.