# Complex data reshaping into wide format where input is a mix of long and wide data

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I am working on fairly complex data. Here is a simplified snapshot as a data frame `df`.

```
ID      Measures              ME1   ME2 X1  X2
53-21   comm - 01 narrate      2    1   NA  NA
53-21   comm - overall         1    NA  NA  NA
53-21   comm - 10 participate  NA   NA  NA  NA
43-65   comm - 02 project      2    3   NA  NA
43-65   comm - 01 narrate      1    1   NA  NA
67-21   comm - 06 action       2    1   NA  NA
67-21   comm - 08 plan         1    1   NA  1
43-65   comm - overall         2    NA  NA  NA
53-21   comm - exhibit         1    1   NA  NA
```

Here:

`ID` = Unique user ID

`Measures` = Name of the item being measured or assessed for a given user

For each `Measure`, users can be graded on up to four different items such as `ME1`, `ME2`,`X1`, and `X2`.

I want to convert this data in a format where items are being placed in rows i.e., one ID per row and their corresponding measures in additional columns. My required reshaped data frame is something like this:

```
ID      comm-01-narrate-ME1 comm-01-narrate-ME2 comm-01-narrate-X1 comm-01-narrate-X2 comm-overall-ME1 comm-overall-ME2 comm-overall-X1 comm-overall-X2 comm-10-participate-ME1 comm-10-participate-ME2 comm-10-participate-X1 comm-10-participate-X2 comm-exhibit-ME1 comm-exhibit-ME2 comm-exhibit-X1 comm-exhibit-X2 comm-02-project-ME1 comm-02-project-ME2 comm-02-project-X1 comm-02-project-X2 comm-06-action-ME1 comm-06-action-ME2 comm-06-action-X1 comm-06-action-X2 comm-08-plan-ME1 comm-08-plan-ME2 comm-08-plan-X1 comm-08-plan-X2
53-21   2                   1                   NA                 NA                 1                NA               NA              NA              NA                      NA                      NA                     NA                     1                1                NA              NA              NA                  NA                  NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                NA                NA               NA               NA              NA
43-65   1                   1                   NA                 NA                 2                NA               NA              NA              NA                      NA                      NA                     NA                     NA               NA               NA              NA              2                   3                   NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                 NA                NA                NA               NA               NA              NA
67-21   NA                  NA                  NA                 NA                 NA               NA               NA              NA              NA                      NA                      NA                     NA                     NA               NA               NA              NA              NA                  NA                  NA                 NA                 2                  1                  NA                NA                1                1                NA              1
```

The `dput()` for the input file `df` is:

```
dput(df)

structure(list(ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L), 
.Label = c("43-65", "53-21", "67-21"), class = "factor"), 
    Measures = structure(c(1L, 7L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 6L), 
    .Label = c("comm - 01 narrate", "comm - 02 project", "comm - 06 action", "comm - 08 plan", "comm - 10 participate", "comm - exhibit", "comm - overall"), class = "factor"), 
    ME1 = c(2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    ME2 = c(1L, NA, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), 
    X1 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
    X2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I am struggling in defining the problem and even starting the processing. The data can be considered `long` but because of multiple columns, it is `wide` as well.

Any advice on how to achieve this output file would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time in reading this post.

**EDIT 1**

From a related post [Convert data from long format to wide format with multiple measure columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589693/convert-data-from-long-format-to-wide-format-with-multiple-measure-columns) I tried the following solution:

```
library(data.table)
df2 = dcast(setDT(df), ID~Measures, 
            value.var=c("ME1", "ME2", "X1", "X2"))
```

However, I get a warning:

```
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
```

This means that the entries in my data are all changed to 1 or NA. I do not want this to happen.

**EDIT 2**

When I test the suggested solution on my original data, it fails. To better explain, I am providing a small sample that closely replicates my original data. None of the existing solutions work.

```
dput(df)

structure(list(
Id = c("39fca07f-d62e-494a-4a86-8dec54836c08", "39fca8ee-fe3f-4c85-ab0a-acb3c2db1b9c", "39fca8ed-f34c-b7e3-4229-111155aabe35", "39fca8e9-1e08-1809-c7a8-d2c8a4bc9b00", "39fc6ae5-0de8-4820-eede-343e738e7a4a", "39fca8e9-fbf9-a098-cf8c-322810997ce9"), DeliverId = c("39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6", "39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6", "39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6", "39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6", "39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6", "39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6"), 
DeliverN = c("1Assess", "1Assess", "1Assess", "1Assess", "1Assess", "1Assess"), 
AssessRId = c("39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b", "39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b", "39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b", "39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b", "39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b", "39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b"), 
AssessRN = c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6"), 
AssessTId = c("1ee2684c99fa", "fd2dbea08b43", "0e0177a33282", "091b8f805553", "6e5b9301116d", "7a307a90de19"), 
AssessTN = c("Comm - 09 Narrate", "Comm - Prog Level Judge", "Comm - O Indi Level Judge", "Comm - 02 Int Prj", "Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate", 
"Comm - 05 Exhibit"), 
S.Time = c("21/05/2020 19:47", "23/05/2020 11:06", "23/05/2020 11:05", "23/05/2020 10:59", "11/05/2020 9:58", "23/05/2020 11:00"), 
F.Time = c("24/05/2020 11:02", "23/05/2020 11:06", "23/05/2020 11:05", 
"23/05/2020 11:00", "23/05/2020 11:04", "23/05/2020 11:03"),     CompletedIndi = c(8L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
TotalIndi = c(8L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), 
Progress = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), 
Build = c("Monice Island", "Pink Lasy", "", "", "", ""), 
Advice = c("Monica", "Chandler", "", "", "", ""), 
TechUserId = c(128L, 129L, 130L, 129L, 129L, 129L), 
TechName = c("Barba", "Raymond", "Raymond", "Raymond", "Raymond","Raymond"), TechEmail = c("barber@123.com", "raymond@123.com", "raymond@123.com", "raymond@123.com", "raymond@123.com", "raymond@123.com"), 
TechLife = c("0 - 2 years", "Over 10 years", "Over 10 years", "Over 10 years", "Over 10 years", "Over 10 years"), 
OtherLife = c("0 - 2 years", "5 - 10 years", "5 - 10 years", "5 - 10 years", "5 - 10 years", "5 - 10 years"), 
PersonUId = c(470L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L), 
PersonDName = c("Tall Tiffany", "Sharp Steff", "Sharp Steff", "Sharp Steff", "Sharp Steff", "Sharp Steff"), 
PersonFName = c("Tall", "Sharp", "Sharp", "Sharp", "Sharp", "Sharp"), PersonLName = c("Tiffany", "Steff", "Steff", "Steff", "Steff", "Steff"), PersonUID = c("2783-4409", "4307-4369", "4307-4369", "4307-4369", "4307-4369", "4307-4369"), 
Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), PYear = c(2023L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L), 
Course = c("Undergrad", "Grad", "Grad", "Grad", "Grad", "Grad"), 
Special = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
Q1 = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
Q2 = c(1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
Q3 = c(1L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
Q4 = c(1L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L), 
Q5 = c(1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
Q6 = c(1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
Q7 = c(1L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
Q8 = c(2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
Q9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
Q10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
ListDetails = c("Missing", "Complete", "Complete", "Complete", "Complete", "Complete")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The desired output is as below:

```
Id                                   DeliverId                            DeliverN AssessRId                            AssessRN AssessTId      S-Time           F-Time             CompletedIndi   TotalIndi   Progress    Build           Advice      TechUserId  TechName    TechEmail       TechLife        OtherLife       PersonDName     PersonFName PersonLName PersonUID Gender PYear  Course      Special ListDetails PersonUId Q1_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q1_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q1_Comm - 09 Narrate Q1_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q1_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q1_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q2_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q2_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q2_Comm - 09 Narrate Q2_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q2_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q2_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q3_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q3_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q3_Comm - 09 Narrate Q3_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q3_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q3_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q4_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q4_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q4_Comm - 09 Narrate Q4_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q4_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q4_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q5_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q5_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q5_Comm - 09 Narrate Q5_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q5_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q5_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q6_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q6_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q6_Comm - 09 Narrate Q6_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q6_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q6_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q7_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q7_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q7_Comm - 09 Narrate Q7_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q7_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q7_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q8_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q8_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q8_Comm - 09 Narrate Q8_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q8_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q8_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q9_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q9_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q9_Comm - 09 Narrate Q9_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q9_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q9_Comm - Prog Level Judge Q10_Comm - 02 Int Prj Q10_Comm - 05 Exhibit Q10_Comm - 09 Narrate Q10_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate Q10_Comm - O Indi Level Judge Q10_Comm - Prog Level Judge X_Comm - 02 Int Prj X_Comm - 05 Exhibit X_Comm - 09 Narrate X_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate X_Comm - O Indi Level Judge X_Comm - Prog Level Judge X.1_Comm - 02 Int Prj X.1_Comm - 05 Exhibit X.1_Comm - 09 Narrate X.1_Comm - 10 Learn Comm Participate X.1_Comm - O Indi Level Judge X.1_Comm - Prog Level Judge
39fca07f-d62e-494a-4a86-8dec54836c08 39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6 1Assess  39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b P1       1ee2684c99fa   21/05/2020 19:47 24/05/2020 11:02   8               8           100         Monice Island   Monica      128         Barba       barber@123.com  0 - 2 years     0 - 2 years     Tall Tiffany    Tall        Tiffany     2783-4409 Female 2023   Undergrad   Yes     Missing     470       NA                   NA                   2                    NA                                  NA                           NA                         NA                   NA                   1                    NA                                  NA                           NA                         NA                   NA                   1                    NA                                   NA                          NA                          NA                  NA                   1                    NA                                  NA                           NA                           NA                  NA                  1                    NA                                  NA                           NA                         NA                   NA                   1                    NA                                  NA                           NA                         NA                   NA                     1                   NA                                  NA                          NA                          NA                  NA                      2                   NA                                  NA                          NA                          NA                  NA                  NA                      NA                                  NA                          NA                          NA                  NA                      NA                  NA                                  NA                              NA                          NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                                  NA                          NA                      NA                      NA                  NA                      NA                                  NA                          NA
39fca8ee-fe3f-4c85-ab0a-acb3c2db1b9c 39fb74ce-d5e6-69f6-f733-ee5fbc4689e6 1Assess  39fb74cf-5fb6-4248-6d08-0e36647e190b P2       fd2dbea08b43   23/05/2020 11:06 23/05/2020 11:06   1               1           100         Pink Lasy       Chandler    129         Raymond     raymond@123.com Over 10 years   5 - 10 years    Sharp Steff     Sharp       Steff       4307-4369 Female 2024   Grad        No      Complete    455       3                    2                    NA                   2                                   3                            1                          2                    2                    NA                   1                                   2                            NA                         3                    2                    NA                   2                                    3                           NA                          3                   1                    NA                   2                                   3                            NA                           2                   2                   NA                   1                                   2                            NA                         1                    1                    NA                   1                                   0                            NA                         1                    2                      NA                  2                                   2                           NA                          1                   2                       NA                  2                                   2                           NA                          NA                  NA                  NA                      NA                                  NA                          NA                          NA                  NA                      NA                  NA                                  NA                              NA                          NA                  NA                  NA                  NA                                  NA                          NA                      NA                      NA                  NA                      NA                                  NA                          NA
```

**Note:** I don't think this question is a duplicate as none of the previous solutions work on my data set. I request you to please open my question again and make it visible please.

I would appreciate any help or advice on why the solutions do not work on my data set.

Comment: In the new desired output, what about the `AssessRN` values P3 to P6.  Are you dropping those

Comment: If I use `df %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = AssessTN, values_from = Q1:X.1)` it does work without any errors or warning.  The data structure involves a lot of columns, so it is not clear and also as you didn't show the P3 to P6, I have some difficulty in understanding

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot_wider` which takes multiple `values_from` columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = Measures, values_from = ME1:X2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 29
  ID    `ME1_comm - 01 na… `ME1_comm - overa… `ME1_comm - 10 par… `ME1_comm - 02 p… `ME1_comm - 06 a… `ME1_comm - 08 p… `ME1_comm - exhi…
  <fct>              <int>              <int>               <int>             <int>             <int>             <int>             <int>
1 53-21                  2                  1                  NA                NA                NA                NA                 1
2 43-65                  1                  2                  NA                 2                NA                NA                NA
3 67-21                 NA                 NA                  NA                NA                 2                 1                NA
# … with 21 more variables: ME2_comm - 01 narrate <int>, ME2_comm - overall <int>, ME2_comm - 10 participate <int>,
#   ME2_comm - 02 project <int>, ME2_comm - 06 action <int>, ME2_comm - 08 plan <int>, ME2_comm - exhibit <int>,
#   X1_comm - 01 narrate <int>, X1_comm - overall <int>, X1_comm - 10 participate <int>, X1_comm - 02 project <int>,
#   X1_comm - 06 action <int>, X1_comm - 08 plan <int>, X1_comm - exhibit <int>, X2_comm - 01 narrate <int>, X2_comm - overall <int>,
#   X2_comm - 10 participate <int>, X2_comm - 02 project <int>, X2_comm - 06 action <int>, X2_comm - 08 plan <int>,
#   X2_comm - exhibit <int>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response. Let me try it on my original data.

Comment: @Sandy In the example there were no duplicate rows.  If there are dupes in the original data, we may need to create a sequence column by Measures

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more on duplicates?
Currently, it seems to be working but, to be honest, I did not consider checking for duplicates.
The solution is so simple and fast, extremely helpful for me.

Comment: @Sandy If there are more than one unique row, then the pivot_wider would return columns with list.  To avoid that you can do `df %>% group_by(Measures) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% ungroup %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Measures, values_from = ME1:X2)`

Comment: Great, I will try that. Your answer clearly solves the question that I asked in my original post. Thank you very much!

Comment: Based on your knowledge and expertise in R programming, can you please advise some useful resources / books that I could begin with? I am planning on investigating in a few R beginner level books.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233302/discussion-between-sandy-and-akrun).

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged when you stumble on an error.  It would make you think why it is causing error and thus be able to understand the behaviors of function ..

Comment: I tried your suggested solution on the original data, however, the results are placed on different rows of the ID.  I am providing additional sample data which shows how the solution fails.