# Convert data from wide format to long format with multiple measure columns

Tags: r, reshape, data-cleaning

I want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589693/convert-data-from-long-format-to-wide-format-with-multiple-measure-columns) but the exact opposite. So say my dataset looks like this:

| ID | X_1990 | X_2000 | X_2010 | Y_1990 | Y_2000 | Y_2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 13 | 16 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 8 | 11 | 14 | 17 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 15 | 18 |

but with a lot more measure variables (i.e. also Z_1990, etc.). How can I get it so that the year becomes a variable and it will keep the different measures, like this:

| ID | Year | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1990 | 1 | 10 |
| A | 2000 | 4 | 13 |
| A | 2010 | 7 | 16 |
| B | 1990 | 2 | 11 |
| B | 2000 | 5 | 14 |
| B | 2010 | 8 | 17 |
| C | 1990 | 3 | 12 |
| C | 2000 | 3 | 15 |
| C | 2010 | 9 | 18 |

Comment: So sorry, I didn't know how to enter tables, but I just fixed it. Let me know if I need to add anything else!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pivot_longer` with `names_sep` argument.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -ID, names_to = c('.value', 'Year'), names_sep = '_')

#  ID    Year      X     Y
#  <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#1 A     1990      1    10
#2 A     2000      4    13
#3 A     2010      7    16
#4 B     1990      2    11
#5 B     2000      5    14
#6 B     2010      8    17
#7 C     1990      3    12
#8 C     2000      6    15
#9 C     2010      9    18
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), X_1990 = 1:3, X_2000 = 4:6, 
    X_2010 = 7:9, Y_1990 = 10:12, Y_2000 = 13:15, Y_2010 = 16:18), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: how would you add more variables in "cols" (not only by ID). Would it be cols = -c(ID, others)? In this case, it doesn't work me. Thank you!